# Attempting zero downtime upgrades but Targetpool is directing traffic to instances that are being torn down

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am attempting to have a zero down time upgrade of my service. So far i have been unsuccessful.  The load balancer is directing traffic to the old instances as they are being taken down despite the fact they are **unhealthy** according to the load balancer's health check. I am using terraform and gcp. The actual service that will be upgraded needs to terminate the TLS connection so this service needs to to use a network load balancer, a target pool. The regional instance group manager is to ensure redundancy in case a zone goes down.

Toy version of terraform where the number of instances are down sized but shows the problem

```
variable "project" {
  type = string
}
variable "region" {
  type = string
  default = "us-central1"
}

provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region = var.region
}

resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "default" {
  base_instance_name = "instance"
  name = "default"

  region = var.region
  target_size = 3
  target_pools = [
    google_compute_target_pool.default.self_link,
  ]

  update_policy {
    minimal_action = "REPLACE"
    type = "PROACTIVE"
    max_surge_fixed = 3
    max_unavailable_fixed = 0
    min_ready_sec = 120
  }

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.template-b.self_link
  }
}

resource "google_compute_address" "default" {
  name = "default"
}

resource "google_compute_target_pool" "default" {
  name = "default"
  region = var.region
  instances = []
  health_checks = [
    google_compute_http_health_check.default.self_link
  ]
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      instances
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_http_health_check" "default" {
  name = "default"
  request_path        = "/"
  check_interval_sec  = 1
  timeout_sec         = 1
  healthy_threshold   = 3
  unhealthy_threshold = 1
}

resource "google_compute_forwarding_rule" "default" {
  name = "default"
  region = var.region
  ip_protocol = "TCP"
  port_range = "80"
  target = google_compute_target_pool.default.self_link
  ip_address = google_compute_address.default.address
}

data "google_compute_network" "default" {
  name = "default"
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "template-b" {
  name = "template-b1"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"

  disk {
    boot = true
    auto_delete = true
    disk_size_gb = 100
    disk_type = "pd-ssd"
    source_image = data.google_compute_image.my_image.self_link
  }

  network_interface {
    network = data.google_compute_network.default.self_link
  }

  metadata_startup_script = file("./startup-scripts/helloworld.sh")

  metadata = {
    instance-env = "SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B"
  }

  tags = [
    "http-server"
  ]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "google_compute_image" "my_image" {
  family  = "ubuntu-1804-lts"
  project = "ubuntu-os-cloud"
}

output "ip-address" {
  value = google_compute_address.default.address
}
```

bootup script that brings up a server that is running on each instance. `startup-scripts/helloworld.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -x
METADATA_BASE=http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1
SOFTWARE_VERSION=$(curl -sfm5 -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" ${METADATA_BASE}/instance/attributes/instance-env)
echo "Hello World! This is ${SOFTWARE_VERSION} from $(hostname -f)" > index.html
python3 -m http.server 80 &
```

The problem i run into is that as i scale down the number of instances from say 6 to 3 i can see that some instances are labelled unhealthy by the health check, but the target pool is still directing traffic to those instances. The documentation for this implies that these instances shouldn't see any traffic.

during the resizing of the number instances from 6 to 3
i ran two shell scripts and got these results
`while [[ 1 ]]; do echo -n "$(date +%s) "; curl -m5 http://${IP_ADDRESS} && sleep 1; done`

```
no timeouts
...
1589838264 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-562f.c.my-project.internal
1589838265 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-42dm.c.my-project.internal
1589838267 curl: (52) Empty reply from server
1589838267 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838272 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-xss8.c.my-project.internal
1589838273 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838278 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-xss8.c.my-project.internal
1589838279 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838284 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-wh9v.c.my-project.internal
1589838285 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838290 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-w47x.c.my-project.internal
1589838292 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5003 milliseconds
1589838297 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5003 milliseconds
1589838302 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-xss8.c.my-project.internal
...
no time outs
```

`while [[ 1 ]]; do echo -n "$(date +%s) "; gcloud compute target-pools get-health default --region us-central1  && sleep 1; done`

```
all six instances are healthy
...
1589838263 ---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-f/instances/instance-xss8
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/instances/instance-w47x
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-wh9v
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: UNHEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-f/instances/instance-rvcl
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-562f
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: UNHEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/instances/instance-42dm
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
1589838266 ---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-f/instances/instance-xss8
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/instances/instance-w47x
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-wh9v
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: UNHEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-f/instances/instance-rvcl
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: UNHEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-562f
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: UNHEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/instances/instance-42dm
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
...
unhealthy for a bit
...
1589838312 ---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-f/instances/instance-xss8
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-c/instances/instance-w47x
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
---
healthStatus:
- healthState: HEALTHY
  instance: compute/v1/projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-b/instances/instance-wh9v
  ipAddress: <IP_ADDRESS>
kind: compute#targetPoolInstanceHealth
```

as you can see by the timestamps from the scripts that the unhealthy instances are still getting traffic.

This same pattern of unhealthy instances getting traffic can be seen when swapping the instance template for the regional instance group manager in terraform for a different one. it can also be seen when bringing up a second regional instance group manager and adding that to the target pool waiting for traffic to go to those new instances then removing the older regional instance group manager from the target pool. I have also tried bringing up a second target pool with its own instance group manager, then changing the forwarding rule, but there i saw over a minute of down time with no traffic even going to either regional instance group.

What can i do to avoid this downtime?

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it follows there was a thirty second interval  during which the Load Balancer kept sending requests to the irresponsive instances.

`gcloud compute target-pools get-health` gives the following timestamps and health statuses:

```
Timestamp 1589838263
instance-rvcl   UNHEALTHY
instance-42dm   UNHEALTHY
instance-562f   HEALTHY

Timestamp 1589838266
instance-rvcl   UNHEALTHY
instance-42dm   UNHEALTHY
instance-562f   UNHEALTHY
```

`curl` output with the health statuses merged:

```
no timeouts
...
1589838263      # instance-562f still HEALTHY, the last response
1589838264 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-562f.c.my-project.internal
1589838265 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-42dm.c.my-project.internal
1589838266      # relative time +0s, instances -rvcl,42dm,562f are UNHEALTHY 
1589838267 curl: (52) Empty reply from server 
1589838267 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838272 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-xss8.c.my-project.internal
1589838273 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838278 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-xss8.c.my-project.internal
1589838279 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838284 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-wh9v.c.my-project.internal
1589838285 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5004 milliseconds
1589838290 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-w47x.c.my-project.internal
1589838292 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5003 milliseconds
1589838297 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 5003 milliseconds  # relative time +30s; instances -rvcl,42dm,562f still UNHEALTHY 
1589838302 Hello World! This is SOFTWARE_VERSION=Version-B from instance-xss8.c.my-project.internal
...
no time outs
```

This may be due to the delay that the Load Balancer needs to recognize that the instance is unhealthy. During this time the Load Balancer keeps sending new requests to the instance.

Once an instance becomes unhealthy, the Load Balancer stops sending new connections there. However, existing connections could be not terminated until the shutdown script switches off the instance. [Shutdown period](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/deleting-instance#delete_timeout) is 90 seconds for normal instances.

Here is an example of the Health Check timeline:

[Load Balancing > Doc > Health checks overview > Example health check](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#example)

See also

[Compute Engine > Doc > Understanding autoscaler decisions > Preparing for instance terminations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/understanding-autoscaler-decisions#preparing_for_instance_terminations)

[Load Balancing > Doc > Health checks overview > How health checks work > Health state](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#health_state)